# Display breadcrumbs on a custom phtml page

Tags: magento-1.9, phtml, local.xml, breadcrumbs

I try to display my breadcrumbs on a custom phtml file.

In a custom controller I have defined an indexAction. After calling http://my-shop.com/auctionlist my page is displayed.

**Controller:**

```
class MyNamespace_AuctionExtend_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {
    public function indexAction() {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
            'Mage_Core_Block_Template',
            'auctionlist',
            array('template' => 'auctionlist/auctionlist.phtml')
        );

        $this->getLayout()->getBlock('root')->setTemplate('page/2columns-right.phtml');
        $this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->setTitle(Mage::helper('core')->__('Auktionsliste'))->append($block);
        $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setTitle(Mage::helper('core')->__('Auktionsliste'));
        $this->_initLayoutMessages('core/session');
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

In my local.xml file I manage all breadcrumb definitions like:

```
<customer_account_login>
    <reference name="breadcrumbs">
        <action method="addCrumb">
            <crumbName>Home</crumbName>
            <crumbInfo>
                <label>Home</label>
                <title>Home</title>
                <link>/</link>
            </crumbInfo>
        </action>
    </reference>
</customer_account_login>
```

How can I call my custom auctionlist file in the local.xml to display the breadcrumbs? This is what I try to get:

```
<auctionlist_index>
    <reference name="breadcrumbs">
        <action method="addCrumb">
            ...
        </action>
    </reference>
</auctionlist_index>
```

(I already tryed that but it doesnt work.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some research and find the answer.

**If anyone runs into the same problem here is my solution:**

At first credits goes to
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8353369/how-can-i-define-block-for-my-magento-controller-in-layout-xml

`auctionlist_index` in my **local.xml** doesnt work because my module is not called, so i changed it to: `auctionextend_index_index` and my breadcrumbs are visible now.

Answer (score 4):

You can set this from your controller action. Below is the reference code.

```
public function IndexAction() {      
  $this->loadLayout();
  $this->getLayout()->getBlock("head")->setTitle($this->__("Auktionsliste"));
        $breadcrumbs = $this->getLayout()->getBlock("breadcrumbs");
  $breadcrumbs->addCrumb("home", array(
            "label" => $this->__("Home Page"),
            "title" => $this->__("Home Page"),
            "link"  => Mage::getBaseUrl()
       ));

  $breadcrumbs->addCrumb("Auktionsliste", array(
            "label" => $this->__("Auktionsliste"),
            "title" => $this->__("Auktionsliste")
       ));

  $this->renderLayout(); 

}
```

Answer (score 1):

By adding below code in phtml file you can set breadcumbs

```
$breadcrumbs = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('breadcrumbs');
$breadcrumbs->addCrumb('home', array('label' => Mage::helper('cms')->__('Home'), 'title' => Mage::helper('cms')->__('Home Page'), 'link' => Mage::getBaseUrl()));
$breadcrumbs->addCrumb('Custom', array('label' => 'Custom', 'title' => 'Custom'));
echo $this->getLayout()->getBlock('breadcrumbs')->toHtml();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this with add **[Custom Breadcrumbs Pages](http://www.onlinecode.org/magento-breadcrumbs-custom-pages/)(Reference)**

```
// get breadcrumbs object
// Magento Breadcrumbs Custom Pages
$_getbreadcrumbs = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('breadcrumbs');

$_getbreadcrumbs->addbreadCrumb('home', array('label'=>Mage::helper('cms')->__('Home'), 'title'=>Mage::helper('cms')->__('Home Page'), 'link'=>Mage::getBaseUrl()));

$_getbreadcrumbs->addbreadCrumb('country', array('label'=>'Country', 'title'=>'All Countries', 'link'=>'http:// onlinecode.org/magento/onlinecodeName/country'));

$_getbreadcrumbs->addbreadCrumb('manufacturer', array('label'=>'State', 'title'=>'States'));
// echo breadcrumbs data
echo $this->getLayout()->getBlock('breadcrumbs')->toHtml();
```

AND

```
<reference name="breadcrumbs">
    <action method="addbreadCrumb">
            <!-- First breadcrumbs name -->
            <name>Home</name>
            <!-- add label, title, link  -->
            <params><label>Home</label><title>Home</title><link>/</link></params>
    </action>
    <action method="addbreadCrumb">
            <!-- add authors  -->
            <name>authors</name>
            <!-- add label, title, link  -->                        
<params><label>Authors</label><title>Authors</title><link>/index.php/managingusers/index/authorlist</link></params>
    </action>
    <action method="addbreadCrumb">
            <!-- add searchlist  -->
            <name>searchlist</name>
            <!-- add label, title, link  -->    
            <params><label>Search List</label><title>SearchList</title><link /></params>
    </action>
</reference>
```

**Reference :: [Magento Breadcrumbs Custom Pages](http://www.onlinecode.org/magento-breadcrumbs-custom-pages/)**

Answer (score 0):

> app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/layout/local.xml

```
<your_layout_handle>
    <reference name="breadcrumbs">
        <action method="addCrumb">
            <name>Home</name>
            <params><label>Home</label><title>Home</title><link>/</link></params>
        </action>
        <action method="addCrumb">
            <name>New page</name>
            <params><label>newpage</label><title>newpage</title></params>
        </action>
    </reference>
</your_layout_handle>
```